# Use SVG as og:image

Tags: facebook-opengraph, social-networking, sharing

Is it possible to use an SVG for an [Open Graph](http://ogp.me/) image?

I tried it and it didn't work with Facebook, however I'm unsure if it's a problem with my SVG or if it's generally not possible.

I did it like this:

```
<meta content="http://www.example.com/mylogo.svg" property="og:image">
```

Comment: I doubt it’s possible at all. Did the [debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) have anything to say about it?

Comment: No, honestly I just put it on one of my pages as a test where there are other images, it just ignored it totally.

Comment: I just ran into the same issue. Switched some pngs to SVG, and Facebook ignored it, even afterI explicitly set `<meta property="og:image" content="image.svg" />`. frustrating. curious if you had any luck fixing this?

Answer (score 90):

OpenGraph does not support .svg as images

http://indiewebcamp.com/The-Open-Graph-protocol#Does_not_support_SVG_images

Answer (score 10):

As of May 2014, Facebook does not formally define what images they support (you can read their [best practices here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content)), though the implication by the optimal sizes (1200 x 630 pixels for high resolution devices and 600 x 315 pixels for standard resolution devices) is that the image must be a raster format.

Comment: As of Jan 14, 2021, Facebook's Sharing Debugger at  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ emits a warning:
Unsupported Image File Extension —
Provided `og:image` URL, `https://example.com/og_image.svg` does not have a supported extension.